# Does Half-Life: Blue Shift have the Half-Life folder?

Tags: half-life

I was looking to play [Half-Life: Decay](https://www.moddb.com/mods/half-life-decay) with my friend but I can't find the required Half-Life folder.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how HL Blueshift and HL Decay are connected. They are two different expansions to the HL game.

Comment: @PlanetAlexander: He is likely referring to the [unofficial Decay PC port](https://www.moddb.com/mods/half-life-decay).

Comment: Because your question is PC-specific you must be playing the [unofficial port](https://www.moddb.com/mods/half-life-decay)? I've added a link to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half-Life: Blue Shift is installed to the main Half-life directory, in `bshift` folder (high-definition models are located in `bshift_hd`).